# Report not being sent

Tags: civireport, cron-job

I have a simple report that should be sent once per day, Cron Jobs do work and if I force sending the related report it's sent.

Looking at the log I can see that when I force the cron job then the action is executed :

`Entité : Job Action : mail_report Synthèse Finished execution of Création comptes WP with result: Succès (1)`

But when running along with all cron jobs it only starts but never ends:

`Entité : Job Action : mail_report Synthèse Starting execution of Création comptes WP`

What could prevent the task to not be terminated?

EDIT 1: a report on an other instance is also not sent, but started

Comment: What hosting is it on?  I've had cron jobs start and not finish because they hit limits and were killed - either exceeding permitted memory or duration limits.

Comment: We hosting our instances on a high-end server with lots of resources. I'll still have a look at memory overflow. Thanks for this hint Aidan.

Comment: how much would you advise for the setting of the time-out? I switched from 120 to 300.

Comment: Are you trying to email the report to more than one contact in the 'to' field?

Comment: good question! I checked and actually I only have one recipient

Comment: on an other Drupal instance Reports are also not sent by the cron job. Very odd situation :-/